# Flummoxed by White Space at Top of Page

Tags: html, space

Can anyone tell me why I have white space at the top of my page:

http://wildwood-design.org/twagons.html

But not this one:

http://wildwood-design.org/index.html

I just can't spot it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `navth` under your slideshow. It's not present on the inner pages, and removing it seems to do the trick.

The `navth` list has no height, but it *does* have a margin - setting the margin to 0 removes the whitespace. Or, seeing as it's not visible to users, you could just set it to `display: none;` instead.

Aside: am I right in thinking you're using a WYSIWG program to generate the code? The design *works*, but all the inline styles are hurting my head and will make the site a pain to maintain in the long run...

Comment: Thanks - why is the nav making a white space though? I want nav and no white space! And the aside - yes the page is a mixture of some site someone else wrote (copied from an ancient template) and my inexperienced dreamweaver antics plus liberal bits of copy and paste. It is hurting my head and causing me pain!

Comment: Updated my answer: you can keep the element in the page, just hide it (or set its margins to 0). Don't forget to tick the answer as 'accepted' if it solves your problem :)

Comment: See http://www.complexspiral.com/publications/uncollapsing-margins/ for a better explanation on what's happening there.

Comment: Hmm still not solved I'm afraid. I'm sure it is to do with the navth but I still get the white space with:#navth li { display:none; width: 50px; float: left; margin: 0px; list-style: none   }. In any case the navth list IS used - it is a series of thumbnails generated by the javascript so I do need a margin and to display it. Annoyingly if I change the doctype to <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> I get no whitespace - but this stops the slideshow from centralizing but only in Internet Explorer! If only I knew what I was doing.

Comment: It's the `UL` you need to change the margin on, not the `LI` - LI is list item (the children of the list), UL is unordered list (the list itself).

Comment: Oh I see. You might have to spell it out to me though. I added : #navth ul {margin :0px; display:none;} but still the same behaviour. Do I need to alter the javascript which generates the unordered list?

Comment: You need to use `ul#navth { margin: 0; display: none } ` if you're using an external stylesheet (`#navth ul` is trying to target a `ul` inside an element which has the id of `navth`), or just adding `margin: 0; display: none` to the HTML page's `ul` tag should do it. You probably don't need both `display: none` and `margin: 0`, but it won't hurt.